# How to git-checkout first application created on OpenShift?

Tags: java, git, openshift

I am new to git (coming from Subversion). I am exploring [OpenShift](https://openshift.redhat.com) and created an account, together with a first application. As I understand, some [code](https://demo-firmflows.rhcloud.com/) has already been created.

I have installed TortoiseGit (I am under windows 7) and I would like to checkout the code created for my application. I believe I must perform a git clone, but with which URL? How can I check-out the code on my local PC?

**Update**

I have deleted my application, installed the client toolset and recreated the application from there. I am facing another issue, but I'll open a separate question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you install their client toolset, as described in their https://openshift.redhat.com/app/getting_started page, and you make a new application, it already does a git clone and sets up the remote repo for you.  The directory will have the same name as the app name you gave when you setup your domain and project.

From there, publishing is simply committing to the master branch and pushing (which are generic basic git).  You should probably start with "git add" for the individual files you add or update, and then:

```
git commit -m "your message"
git push
```