# Where I have to deploy my app files after logging in to openshift using filezilla

Tags: php, deployment, openshift

> I logged into openshift application using filezilla.

Earlier for normal website `i just drag and drop files  at www directory` its works pretty fine but in at this case i found some other folders and `i am unable to get an idea where should i drop my php app in at this particular machine.` I am unable to locate where the index file is located also. if I am using git for the deployment of application it works pretty fine.

Comment: can you give the folder list?

Comment: 1)Php myadmin 2)php 3)Mysql 4)git 5)app-root 6)app-deployment 7).tmp 8).ssh 9).sandbox 10).openshift_shh 11).gem 12).env 13).drush 14).composer 15).auth Thease are the list of the folders i am finding in openshift

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Openshift makes it easy to upload program changes by checking out the container. Adding the code and the pushing it.

see [How to git-checkout first application created on OpenShift?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11366396/how-to-git-checkout-first-application-created-on-openshift) on how to do that.

I'm not sure about the structure when you use filezilla to connect to the Openshift container, but it should be similar to the checked out structure

index.php              Template PHP index page
.openshift/            Location for OpenShift specific files
    action_hooks/      See the Action Hooks documentation 
    markers/           See the Markers section below
    pear.txt           List of pears to install

Depending on what cartridge you are using:

1. php/          # for backward compatibility with OpenShift Origin v1/v2
2. public/       # Zend Framework v1/v2, Laravel, FuelPHP, Surebert etc.
3. public_html/  # Apache per-user web directories, Slim Framework etc.
4. web/          # Symfony etc.
5. www/          # Nette etc.
6. ./            # Drupal, Wordpress, CakePHP, CodeIgniter, Joomla, Kohana, PIP etc.

See https://developers.openshift.com/en/php-repository-layout.html for more details.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

goto `app-root > repo`

put your files in this folder. if you put a `index.php`, it will be accessible through the web.

but there's a more convenient method.

create a folder name `php` inside the `repo` folder and openshift will use it as a document root. which means all other files will be unaccessible from the public.

**conclusion**

put all other files in *app-root>repo*. put the *index.php* in the `php` folder and link other files accordingly.

*optional:*
use `GIT`. its easy and way more convenient than sftp. you need to learn only 4 commands.

- git add
- git commit
- git push
- git clone

that's it!

## edit1

> IF php/ dir exists THEN DocumentRoot=php/
>   ELSE IF public/ dir exists THEN DocumentRoot=public/
>   ELSE IF public_html/ dir exists THEN DocumentRoot=public_html/
>   ELSE IF web/ dir exists THEN DocumentRoot=web/
>   ELSE IF www/ dir exists THEN DocumentRoot=www/
>   ELSE DocumentRoot=/

above is the priority of document roots in openshift. use whatever you like.

Comment: if i am deleting the index file from the folder the machine is showing 404 but if i am adding the old file its not showing the change and the seccond method you told is not working

Comment: if you will put the old file there, ofcourse it wont show any change. replace that index.php with your new one. then you will see the changes... and check the edit.

Answer (score 0):

Had the same problem. You need to turn off APC cache. This can be done via an .htaccess file:
      php_flag apc.cache_by_default Off

Comment: Also remember that pushing will overwrite any changes made via ftp.

Comment: This does not answer the question where to upload files at all. Also, you should update your answer instead of adding a comment.

Comment: If you are not having reputations then you are unable to comment. If somebody want to comment what they will do?.

Comment: One more problem where i can find this .htaccess file or if i want to upload a new file what directory i should prefer?.